# How to throw exception in VIsual C++ using a wchar_t string?

Tags: visual-c++, exception, unicode-string

I have legacy code which I am incrementally porting to Unicode characters in Visual C++ (wchar_t).  I've encountered this bit of code that I'd like to convert:

```
char tmp[256];
sprintf(tmp, "stuff");
throw exception(tmp);
```

I want to change it to something like this (this gives me a compile error on exception):

```
wchar_t tmp[256];
swprintf(tmp, "stuff");
throw exception(tmp);
```

So far I haven't found any document to give me the Unicode equivalent for throw exception, can anyone help me?

Of  course I could convert my "tmp" back into a char string, but that just seems silly to have to do that.

Comment: This is a problem with the standard C++ library, it doesn't have an std::exception constructor that accepts a wchar_t*.  Unicode gets a cold shoulder in C++.  You'll have to do something icky like converting to utf-8.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer!  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::exception` does not support `wchar_t` strings, so you will have to either convert your `wchar_t` buffer into a separate `char` buffer, or do not switch to a `wchar_t` buffer to begin with as `sprintf()` does support formatting Unicode input via its `%S` and `%ls` formatting specifiers, eg:

```
char tmp[256]; 
sprintf(tmp, "%ls", wchar_t data here); 
throw exception(tmp);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does appear to be the answer!